# Reading contents in multiples files block by block and writing them block by block in a single file using Java

Tags: java, file

Here is my source code. I got the reading part but need a simple logic for my writing part which I"m not getting. Here in my current logic, data gets overwritten and I'm always able to see the last block of read data in my written file.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
java.io.FileNotFoundException;
java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
public class LoadTest 
 {  
public void readFiles(File file) throws FileNotFoundException
       {
        int fsize = (int) file.length();
        int part = (fsize/4)+(fsize%4);
        byte[] block = new byte[part]; 
        FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(file);
        try
        {
            int val=-1;
            do
            {
                int bytesread =0;
                while(bytesread<part)
                    {
                        val = fin.read(block, bytesread, part-bytesread);
                        if (val<0)
                            break;
                        bytesread += val;

                    }
                writeFiles(block,bytesread);                            
            }
            while(val>=0);
            fin.close();
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
public void writeFiles(byte[] block, int len) throws IOException
{
    int byteswritten = 0;
    FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream("input.csv");
    fout.write(block, byteswritten, len+byteswritten);
    byteswritten +=len;
    fout.close();
}


public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
{  
    LoadTest testobj = new LoadTest();
    String folder = "/Users/NiranjanSubramanian/Desktop/TestFiles";
    File dir = new File(folder);
    File[] files = dir.listFiles();
    System.out.println("Started");
    for( File entry: files)
    {  
        testobj.readFiles(entry);

    }
    System.out.println("Ended");

}
```

}

Comment: Simple 2-line fix: `FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream("input.csv", true);` and `fout.write(block);`

Comment: Explanation: you're seeking to *append*, so use the appropriate [`FileOutputStream` constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream(java.io.File,%20boolean)). Better response: you should only use one stream for the file.

Comment: `fout.write(block, 0, len)` rather

Comment: @oldrinb Thanks a lot, works fine ya didn't think about appending, changed the constructor now

Comment: Remember to accept the answer which helped you most.

Comment: @oldrinb sure done!! I want to do the same using NIO but in a different format, I've 2 functions readfile(), which reads n maps the file into buffer, i pass this buffer into readrecord(), which reads the contents of the buffers in blocks. I use channel.size() but it gives me the size as a whole not in blocks. Can you pls help? I"m a beginner

Comment: if you want to deal with `FileChannel` I'd just use `transferFrom` or `transferTo`

Comment: You don't need to know the size of the file in blocks, and if you do you just need to divide the bytes by the blocksize and adjust for a possible final incomplete block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my comments for how to solve the issue in a simple manner. However, let me suggest to you a simple alternative to do what you're asking.

```
final Path dir = Paths.get("/Users/NiranjanSubramanian/Desktop/TestFiles");
try (final OutputStream out = Files.newOutputStream(Paths.get("input.csv"))) {
  for (final Path file : Files.newDirectoryStream(dir)) {
    Files.copy(file, out);
  }
}
```

This relies on Java 7's new file API but is (at least in my opinion) a far cleaner solution.

Answer (score 0):

There are some libs that handle it for you, or even NIO, but the simplest way to do it is the following:

```
int read = 0;
byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(yourInputFile);
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(yourOutputFile);

while((read = fis.read(buff)) >= 0){
    fos.write(buff, 0, read);
}
fos.flush();
fos.close();
fis.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Open the file in append mode.. your code will override since the default is overwrite, not append.

To append you need to pass the append parameter as true. 
change

```
FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream("input.csv");
```

to

```
FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream("input.csv", true);
```

Comment: This answer is actually incorrect. This will not solve the `IndexOutOfBoundsException`

Answer (score 0):

How to copy streams in Java:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[8192]; // or whatever you like really
int count;
while ((count = in.read(buffer)) > 0)
{
  out.write(buffer, 0, count);
}
```

Note that you don't need the entire input in memory before you start writing, so you are saving both time and space; and handling partial reads including the probable final one is trivially easy.